# Able to run live stream on wowza on my local,but not able to see the live streaming on other system in LAN

Tags: rtmp, http-live-streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

i getting a problem. on my localhost live stream is working properly with wowza media server and using live encoder but when i run on client LAN Network it gives==
server not found: rtmp://localhost:80/live not found
 what is the problem ... 
firewall issue or some other 
my wowza ip address is rtmp://localhost:1935/live
stream:livestream

Comment: You might want to be more specific in your question.  You indicate your wowza ip address is localhost. If you are trying to reach another server using 'localhost' from your machine, that would obviously be a problem.

Comment: thanks grant but now i able to run........

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" points to own computer.

If you install a rtmp server on your own computer, that setting will allow you to test but nobody else will be able to access from a different computer because setting will point to their own computers.

You need to setup Red5 on a server (accessible by all clients) and rtmp address based on a publicly accessible IP or domain.